# Is it possible for the SQL Server Full Text Search read a reversed sentence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if there is a way that a SQL Server Full Text search can read or compare a sentence or text with the same value

for example:

> Search text: siomai big pack-by-6-pcs

with the same result for:

> Search text: big pack-by-6-pcs siomai

because the only method I used to know is like

```
select * from productList where description like '%+ param +%'
```

so if I give this query the parameter "siomai big pack-by-6-pcs" it would not give the same result of "big pack-by-6-pcs siomai"

I have been searching for the full text search of SQL Server and wondering if it would work this way, I want to know if there could be a way?

Comment: If you had the sentence data available in reverse order, you could add a column to contain it, then reindex with full text to include that reversed order column.

Comment: Pardon, but may you detailed it for me? sorry for the trouble

Comment: I've little experience working with full text search in SQL Server, but from what I read the index can cover multiple columns.  So, it you had a column containing your reverse sentence content, then it would be convered by FTS if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You could split the text to use an IN statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I should learn it further thanks for further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to search by words instead of whole sentence, So, You need to extract words from your search sentence then check each words in the sentence and then when sentence has all words it is matched:

```
declare @sentence nvarchar(255) = 'big pack-by-6-pcs siomai';

with words as (
    select n.x.value('.', 'nvarchar(255)') w
    from (
        select cast('<w>'+replace(@sentence,' ', '</w><w>')+'</w>' as xml) x
        ) t
    cross apply t.x.nodes('/w') as n(x)
)
select t.txt
from yourTable t
left join words w
  on ' ' + t.txt + ' ' like '% ' + w.w + ' %'  -- where sentence contains word
group by t.txt
having count(w.w) = (select count(*) from words); -- sentence has all words
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce331/4)

Comment: I havent tested it yet but I think I got you point, It seem I got 2 answers in this question I will try both and figure what is more efficient. Thanks for this